# How to get only year from unix time stamp in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time, '%y')
```

this only return last two digits of the year `17`.I need an exact results like `2017`.

Comment: use `%Y`.......

Comment: thanks.It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Based of the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php you should be using an upper case Y.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time, '%Y')
```

Comment: I need one more info,how to achieve the following one 'date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given' in 'C:\wamp64\www\WorkDesk_Sprint_2.0\Monthly_leave_reports.php' line 77